# Format Specifier was invalid asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a series of dropdown lists that on change is to call a function that converts overall value from binary to decimal and hex. I continue to get this error and do not know what is wrong.

Here is the dropdown list code

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="r1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="convert" AutoPostBack="true" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the behind page code

```
   protected void convert(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal rDec = ((Convert.ToInt32(r1.SelectedValue)) * 128) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r2.SelectedValue)) * 64) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r3.SelectedValue)) * 32) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r4.SelectedValue)) * 16) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r5.SelectedValue)) * 8) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r6.SelectedValue)) * 4) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r7.SelectedValue)) * 2) + ((Convert.ToInt32(r8.SelectedValue)) * 1);
    string rHex = rDec.ToString("X");
    string rDecStr = rDec.ToString();
```

The function is closed there are just other parts that are unaffected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring rDec as int instead of decimal.